# My question is still not being deleted after asking for moderator intervention

Tags: support, flags, deleted-questions, moderation

I have a question on Workplace that I regretted posting almost immediately afterwards. People were researching my background and making critical remarks about my programming skill. It's not something I want in the public domain and associated with my name via search results.

But somebody posted an answer very quickly so I can't delete it. This was two days ago; I immediately flagged it for moderator intervention requesting it be closed and saying why. Two days later, it has still not been deleted and I'm getting comment notifications.

Am I being impatient - is taking longer than 2 days to respond to a deletion request normal?

Has my deletion request been denied and I have not been alerted?

Do I have any way to delete the question?

Comment: As a note, in future you might ask that a question be disassociated rather than deleted (assuming it is in scope for the site).

Comment: @Catija not sure how to do that.

Comment: Why don't you go to the chat room and talk to a moderator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You asked for the question to be closed - it was closed.

Just now you flagged again asking for your question to be deleted - it probably will be when the flag gets handled, but you've also scheduled your *account* to be deleted in about two hours, so that'll probably happen first (and accomplish the same thing: since the question is downvoted and closed, it'll get deleted along with your Workplace account).

In between now and then, you can track the status of your flags from [your profile on The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/47716).

Comment: Hah. This confused me seeing the results.

Answer (score 6):

You seem a little impatient to me indeed. Handling a flag can take some time. Moderators work around the clock to handle tons of flags. Before they handle some flags, they might want to discuss how to handle it with other moderators. That takes time.

Requesting to delete your account instead of being patient only gives moderators more work and also the user who spent time answering your question will lose his gained reputation due to the deletion of your account (downvoted closed questions will be deleted too). That isn't very nice to him, is it?

Next time, flag and ask to disassociate the question from your account. Your account will remain intact, just the question will be attributed to an anonymous user.

Comment: My question has something like 6 downvotes and is closed. Does it really matter if somebody has an upvoted answer? You're not pulling my pity strings trying to defend some one else's reputation. I want to close the question because answers & comments include defamatory remarks against me. The fact that I can't readily do this is why I consider the site flawed and wanted to remove my account.

Comment: @maxpleaner other peoples answers do matter, yes. If there are comments and answers that are defamatory in any way that goes against [Be Nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) then flag that content, but you can't simply delete everything because you disagree with what other people have said.

Comment: For what it's worth, the comments on the question that were "offensive" here were purged two days ago.